# Any OSS .Net FTP (client) with TLS and SSL?

Tags: c#, .net, open-source, ftp

Does anyone know of an open source library that does ftp-client with TLS and SSL for dotNET?

We are using a commercial library now but we are not very happy with it, so we are thinking of switching. So instead of rolling our own, are there any lgpl (or equivalent) librarys out there?

Or - If we have to roll our own (it will be a LGPL or BSD or apache style licence), does anyone know of a half finished code base we can start with?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Take a look at these libraries if FtpWebRequest with SSL enabled is not sufficient:

- http://code.google.com/p/sshsync/ - SshSync : Directory synchronisation via SSH
- http://ftpclient.codeplex.com - FtpRequest library for .NET 2.0
- http://www.rebex.net/ftp.net/

Comment: This seems enough to get me started. Thanks.

Comment: The Rebex FTP.NET does not support TLS/SSL. The TLS/SSL version is named Rebex FTP/SSL for .NET and is available at http://www.rebex.net/ftp-ssl.net/

Answer (score 2):

Wel, [FtpWebRequest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.ftpwebrequest.aspx) supports SSL via [EnableSsl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.ftpwebrequest.enablessl.aspx) (using "`AUTH TLS`") - is that sufficient?

Comment: Generally FtpWebRequest  is not sufficient because it lacks implicit SSL support.
http://www.rebex.net/kb/tls-ssl-explicit-implicit/default.aspx

Answer (score 0):

There are .Net bindings for libcurl [here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/libcurl-net/). It looks like the last release was in 2005, so maybe that could be the "half finished" codebase you're looking for. libcurl itself is under bsd, and is a widely used library, so it would seem worthwhile to use it.